# Urgent help! What statistical test to use (dental thesis)

Tags: kruskal-wallis-test

The primary aim of this study is to compare tongue posture and function in children with an unilateral posterior crossbite UPCB who were treated with maxillary expansion in combination with orofacial myofunctional therapy (OMT) versus children who received maxillary expansion only.
Secondly, the effect of maxillary expansion only on tongue posture and function will be evaluated.

All subjects included are evaluated for tongue posture and function. The children with an infantile swallowing pattern are randomly assigned to two groups: The experimental group (EXP + OMT) (receiving orthodontic maxillary expansion and OMT) or the control group (EXP) (receiving orthodontic maxillary expansion only). The children presenting a normal swallowing pattern, are assigned to a third group (CtEXP) (orthodontic maxillary expansion only).
Data registration takes place at different timepoints. The first registration moment is at baseline before any treatment has taken place (pre-treatment, T0). After the active expansion phase and before start of the retention phase, with or without OMT, new data is collected (post-treatment, T1). Once OMT is completed (this takes on average 10-20 weeks) and the patient has been in retention for at least 3 months the post-retention data were collected (T2). The data that are collected at the before mentioned time points, is tongue posture and -function.
To acquire tongue posture, conventional 2DUS imaging can be used. The transducer is placed in the midsagittal plane. The participants are asked to remain still and relaxed while no further instructions are given. Once a stable posture of the tongue is obtained, at least two images are acquired. After image acquisition in the midsagittal plane, the same process is repeated, but with the transducer positioned in the frontal plane.
Tongue function during swallowing can be visualized using two-dimensional B- and M-mode ultrasonography. The transducer is placed in the midsagittal plane and the M-line is positioned through the tongue tip. Patients are asked to remain still. Once the M-line is almost flat and constant, the patients are asked to swallow. This is repeated at least 3 times. If a patient has difficulties with swallowing, they are given a small amount of water to drink. However, only empty swallows are to be evaluated. The range of movement of a certain point on the scanning line will be determined in millimetres. The swallowing pattern can be diagnosed according to the action of the genioglossus muscle, as described by Peng et al. (2003).

The images will be exported to a personal computer for QUALITATIVE analysis of tongue posture and QUANTITATIVE analysis of tongue function.

Would be great to hear your advice, I can't wrap my head around it.
Kind regards

Comment: Was this supposed to be an edit to your other question? https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/566237/313631